# Binary search vs fixing one digit at a time

Tags: algorithm, matlab, scientific-computing

Problem: I want to search a real number `x_0` such that `f(x_0)=0`. We only know that `f` is monotonic increasing, derivative-free, `x_0` is real positive, but not extremely large so that the program won't terminate.

I wrote a program for this when I didn't take an algorithm course, let's call this method `alternative search`.

The way to do is initialize step-size `h` and increment from the left. If `f(x_0)>0`, then step back, and increment by `h/10` from now on. In other word, fixing `x_0` one digit at a time, and terminate when the step-size is very small.

How would this method compare with binary search (or someone calls it bisection)?

My instinct tells me that each time `alternative search` solves one tenth of the problem, compared with one half, is slower. Should be right, am I?

Comment: Just consider how often you evaluate `f` in both cases to get the interval down to roughly the same size.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only interested in an answer to your immediate question, skip to the second section.
In this first section, I explain how to actually use binary search in your case.

### Binary search

First of all, this problem **cannot be solved solely by binary search**, as you need an interval [a,b] in which your solution x* with f(x*) = 0 lies.
Such an interval could for example be found using the **exponential search** algorithm:

- Start with a value x0 such that f(x) < 0
- As long as f(x) < 0, multiply x by 2 *(or another fixed factor > 1)*

This way, your algorithm terminates after at most log2(x*/x0) steps with a value x for which we know that f(x) < 0 and f(2x) > 0. We can thus use this interval [x, 2x] in our binary search.

Also, if your solution x* is a real number, binary search in general **cannot give you the exact solution**, only an approximation (more specifically an interval) with arbitrary accuracy, as a real number can have infinitely many digits. In practice, a computer has only limited accuracy, so the algorithm will always terminate.

In the binary search algorithm, instead of terminating when the midpoint of the current interval is the correct solution, you terminate when the *length of the current interval* is below your *required accuracy*.

As the length of the interval is halved with every step, if your start interval has length *L* and your required accuracy is *e*, your algorithm terminates after log2(*L*/*e*) steps.

When we combine these algorithms together, the overall solution is to

1. Find an interval [a, b] containing x* using exponential search
2. Find an approximation to x* in [a, b] using binary search

As we know that the interval returned by the exponential search [x, 2x] contains x*, the overall algorithm takes log2(x*/x0) + log2(x/e) steps, which is approximately log2(x*²/(e x0)),
since x <= x* <= 2x

### Back to your question

Since you mentioned that you want to fix one digit at a time, I'm guessing that you have already chosen *h* such that it takes at most 10 steps to reach a value x such that f(x) > 0. Otherwise, this is more or less a linear search which is much slower than binary search to begin with.

The simplest way to see the answer to your question is to look at the logarithmic length of the interval that you consider for your solution:

- With binary search, the search interval length is *halved* with every iteration, so log2(L) becomes log2(L/2) = log2(L) - 1
- With your algorithm, the search interval length is reduced to 10% with at most 10 iterations, so after 10 steps log2(L) becomes log2(L/10) = log2(L) - 3.3219...
  If we look at a single step, this boils down to a reduction of at least 0.33219..., which means in the *worst case* your algorithm is 3 times as slow as binary search for the same accuracy.
  *However*, this is assuming that you always have to take 10 steps, so if we assume the digits to be distributed uniformly at random, then we would only need 5 steps on average for every digit, making your algorithm only ~30% slower than binary search